# Creating job from existing job which located in other view

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have several view tabs (view1(Job1,...), view2()). I'm trying to create job in 'view2' from existing Job1 and get "Error: No such job". May be someone faced with such issue?

p.s. in scope of one view everything is ok

Comment: Don't you have a "general" tab with all jobs listed? Try it again from there

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write path to job - 'view/job'

Answer (score 0):

There is default view "All". Try it from there.